# Abrir puertos en linux ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, puertos

necesito abrir el puerto 8443 en mi computadora, investigue y lo hago con

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 8443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

pero al hacer *netstat -tuna* no aparece :(

Estoy haciendolo bien o estoy revolviendo las cosas?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Si no hay ningun programa escuchando al puerto, nada va a aparercer con netstat si abre el puerto con iptables o no.  iptables solamente permita que el data llegue al puerto.

Comment: Asi es como comenta Duston, IpTables es solo un firewall que permite o niega el acceso por diferentes puertos, protocolos, etc., y si al realizar el netstat no te aparece el puerto significa que ninguna aplicacion esta usandolo, intuyo que tratas de ejecutar una aplicacion web en java con certificado SSL, te recomiendo primero verifiques que la aplicacion se este ejecutando sobre el puerto 8443 o que tu configuracion este correcta